# Soccer database design

Tags: database-design

I've a problem with my database design.

I want to do an app to mantein a soccer league, so I have tables to record associations, teams, players, coachs and so on and now I have a problem with competitions.

So, I have a table competition to record competition's data like season, name and type. I've another table to record team's specific data. An example can be, competition like English Premier League and team can be Manchester United, but Barcelona from Spain is record too. So I want to create a table that relation a team with a competition like "Competing Teams" where store the teams available or member for that competition.

How can I store the points, matches and other stuffs of Manchester in that English Premier League??

**EDIT**

I have this sketch of my idea

[image: My design]

Comment: Hello Juan and welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a very broad question giving way to dozens of open-ended answers. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) about what type of questions should be asked here.

Comment: yes..I found another post here but no one answer my question. They don't have responses that help me. Sorry by the way..

Comment: @LukasEder: There's an ESL issue here. The question is not well put together but this is fairly common db design confusion and the answer to is usually junction/join tables.

Comment: Your sketch seems to show that you can store points and matches in the "match" table; what's the question?

Comment: In the match table?I don't think so..but my question is how can I store points, match played, match lose and so on? I need table or just calculate when I need to show that data to my users?

Answer (score 0):

You could be storing them in the table everytime a team wins/draws/loses a game, making the needed operations with the respective points, or you can have a table of matches, and make a COUNT for example where Team 1 won in season 3 for example.